# View with embedded template can't be rendered

Tags: ember.js

Giving a simple sample app with Ember 1.0.0-rc.1:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: 'application' });
App.IndexView  = Ember.View.extend({ 
    template : Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello new Ember!')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nL5vf/

IndexView can't be rendered because during rendering it's view is set to 'undefined'. Is it intentional?

Comment: Have you linked the wrong fiddle?

Comment: Oh, right, will correct it ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can't replace the template of any routed view in this fashion. You can do this for other views however.

The following renders nothing:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello new Ember!')
});
```

But this does:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello new Ember!')
});
```

(template)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{view App.MyView}}
</script>
```

I'll have to let someone more qualified weigh in as to whether or not this is intentional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is apparently a bug, see the discussion here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2212